# Updating Access db using c# form application

Tags: c#

I have written a code to do the above mentioned task. There are no errors but the access db is not getting updated.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbConnection mycon = new OleDbConnection();
        mycon.ConnectionString =@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Dinesh\C#\GIS_Power\WindowsFormsApplication1\bin\Power_DB1";
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
        command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Table1 (Emp_ID,Asset_ID)VALUES('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "')";
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not execute the command. Please execute the insert statement then only it will insert data into database

This will solve your problem.

```
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("//Isert statment here", mycon);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: In that case rate would be much appreciate :)

Answer (score 2):

**Problem1 :** you need to execute the command using `ExecuteNonQuery()` Method.

**Problem 2:** You did not open the Connection with Database by calling `Open()` method from Connection object.

**Problem 3:** you did not assign the `Connection` object to the `Command` object.

**Suggestion:** your `INERT INTO` statement is open to `SQL Injection Attacks`, so i would suggest you to use `Parameterised queries` to avoid them.

**Complete Code:**

```
OleDbConnection mycon = new OleDbConnection();
mycon.ConnectionString =@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Dinesh\C#\GIS_Power\WindowsFormsApplication1\bin\Power_DB1";
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();

command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Table1 (Emp_ID,Asset_ID) VALUES(@empID,@assetID)";
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empID",textBox1.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@assetID",textBox2.Text);
mycon.Open();
command.Connection=mycon;
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: suggestion: use `using` for connection and (perhaps?) command.

Answer (score 0):

You created connection string but didn't open the connection.

You created the query but didn't execute it.

**Solution:**

You need to `open` the `connection` and `execute` the query as well.

**Code:**

```
OleDbConnection mycon = new OleDbConnection();
mycon.ConnectionString =@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Dinesh\C#\GIS_Power\WindowsFormsApplication1\bin\Power_DB1";
mycon.Open(); //opening connection

OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Table1 (Emp_ID,Asset_ID)VALUES('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "')";
command.ExecuteNonQuery();    //executing query

mycon.Close();    //close the connection after executing the query
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
 mycon.open()
 command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Table1 (Emp_ID,Asset_ID)VALUES('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "')";
 command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```